# How do I set Header or Title for CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, .net, checkedlistbox

I have 3 CheckedListBox. I need to identify them by name. How do I add Header or Title to a CheckedListBox rather than using a Groupbox for providing header/title?

To be more precise, here is a sample

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand. Need more clarification. You need to identify them in code or for the user in the interface?

Comment: Identify for the user in interface

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: You could simply use nicely styled Labels..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no out-of-the-box way to do that. You could solve it by creating custom control containing a label(s) + checkboxlist or just simply adding labels to the form itself. I know, that's a pain, but currently there's no header/title property in [`CheckedListBox` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes Mr.Adrian. I tried a lot. I started using the CheckedListBox surrounded with a groupbox and gave heading for that groupbox

Comment: That might be actually the best way to go if you consider setting inner CheckListBox's `Dock` property to `Fill`.